# Hibernate criteria, two entities

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Lets say I have a query :

`SELECT one FROM EntityOne one, EntityTwo two
WHERE one.id = two.otherId AND two.someValue = 2`

I'd like to transform it using Criteria tools but don't know to how fetch

thanks in advance

Comment: You'll only be able to do that if you fix your entities and use associations between them, instead of using IDs referencing other entities. That's also what will allow you to get all the twos of a one, and get the one of a two. Read the chapter about associations in the documentation and create a OneToMany/ManyToOne bidirectional association.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code on how you can get results using `Criteria`:

**EntityOne.java**

```
@Entity
public class EntityOne {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entity", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<EntityTwo> entities = new HashSet<EntityTwo>();
    public EntityOne(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public void addEntity(EntityTwo entity) {
        this.entities.add(entity);
    }
    // Default constructor, setters & getters
}
```

**EntityTwo.java**

```
@Entity
public class EntityTwo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int id;
    String name;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "entity_one_id")
    private EntityOne entity;
    public EntityTwo(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    // Default constructor, setters & getters
}
```

Code to save some entities to database:

```
    EntityOne eo1 = new EntityOne("Entity eo1");
    EntityTwo et1 = new EntityTwo("one");
    EntityTwo et2 = new EntityTwo("two");

    eo1.addEntity(et1);
    eo1.addEntity(et2);
    et1.setEntity(eo1);
    et2.setEntity(eo1);

    EntityOne eo2 = new EntityOne("Entity eo2");
    EntityTwo et3 = new EntityTwo("three");
    EntityTwo et4 = new EntityTwo("four");

    eo2.addEntity(et3);
    eo2.addEntity(et4);
    et3.setEntity(eo2);
    et3.setEntity(eo2);

    session.save(eo1);
    session.save(eo2);
```

Now the code for getting records using `Criteria`:

```
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(EntityOne.class, "e1");
    criteria.createAlias("e1.entities", "e2");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("e2.name", "two"));

    List<EntityOne> entityList = criteria.list();
    for (EntityOne entityOne : entityList) {
        System.out.println(entityOne.getName());
        for (EntityTwo entity : entityOne.getEntities()) {
            System.out.println("->" + entity.getName());
        }
    }
```

Output will be:

```
Entity eo1
->two
->one
```